# Cannot call method from another class (Java)

Tags: java, oop

In the first class I have:

```
package example.identification;

import example.common.InvalidDataException;

public class IdentifiableImpl implements Identifiable {

    private String identifier;

    public IdentifiableImpl(String id) throws InvalidDataException {
        setIdentifier(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public final void setIdentifier(String id) throws InvalidDataException {
        if (id == null || id.length() == 0) {
            throw new InvalidDataException("Null or empty ID passed to setIdentifier");
        }
        identifier = id;
    }
}
```

In the second class I have:

```
package example.identification;
public class IdentifiableTest {

@Test
    public void testGetIdentifier() {
        IdentifiableImpl instance = new IdentifiableImpl();
        instance.setIdentifier("Test");
    }
```

The problem is in the second class with the line `instance.setIdentifier("Test");`  There is an error reported by the IDE on that line that says "Cannot find symbol."

My question is, why can I not call the `setIdentifier("Test")` method on `instance` ?

Comment: [Works for me.](http://ideone.com/326VBF) Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your second class doesn't even have a class declaration.  This is probably what is causing the error.

Comment: Same here... unable to replicate

Comment: When I added the class identifier it also worked for me.

Comment: Ok strange...I am at a complete loss.  Thanks for verifying it works for guys.

Comment: Are you sure your first class compiled fine? If the class file is not generated (due to a compile error or something), your second class wouldn't see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a constructor in your IdentifiableImpl.java class and you're missing a curly brace in your IdentifiableTest.java class

You need the constructor or you won't be able to create the instance. You can't call `setIdentifier("Test")` on `instance` because it was never created.

Added Constructor in IdentifiableImpl

```
public IdentifiableImpl() {

}
```

Fixed brace in testGetIdentifier

```
public void testGetIdentifier() {
    IdentifiableImpl instance = new IdentifiableImpl();
    instance.setIdentifier("Test");
    System.out.println(instance.getIdentifier());
}
```

It works fine for me after these changes

Comment: This does not answer the question, generally pure code dump answers with no explanation are low quality.

Comment: It's not a code dump to supply the single missing component.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Tried that but still doesn't work.  So strange.

Comment: Can you show us both classes as they are in your code, rather than just snippets?

Comment: Sure, I just posted a more complete code set.